Loadmore search results not showing new results?
I have search results which will show load more button but when search for new result it is started from the already incremented value how to avoid this
     jQuery(document).on("click", '#load-more', function(event) { 
 
      //jQuery("#more_posts").css("display",'none'); // Disable the button, temp.
         var get_query_value = jQuery('body').find('#s').val();
 
    jQuery("#loadingImage").show();
       load_main_posts(get_query_value);
  });

  var ppp = 3; // Post per page 
      var  pageNumbers = 1; 
 function load_main_posts(get_query_value){ 
     
  var $latest_content = jQuery('#latest_content'); 
pageNumbers++;   
    var str1 = 'pageNumber=' + pageNumbers + '&ppp=' + ppp+ '&action=load_search_results'+ 
   '&query='+get_query_value ;   
       //console.log(str1) ;
       jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
      url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
      data : str1,     
     
    success: function(response){   
        console.log(pageNumbers);
        console.log(response.length);
         if (pageNumbers >= response.max) {
            console.log("teststa");
            jQuery("#load-more").hide();
         }          
         jQuery("#ajax-posts").append(response.html);    
         jQuery("#loadingImage").hide();         
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log("error");
    }

});
return false;

}

Can you explain more please.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems you have hardcoded your pageNumber as 1 always.
var  pageNumbers = 1; 

So every time you click on "Load More" this value will be incrementing even if you are searching for new term.
My approach would be to store the pageNumber value in "Load More" button.
<button data-pageNumber="1" id="load-more">Load More</button>

And when you click on load more just update the data-pageNumber to +1.
And if you do a new search then update the value back to "1".
